# Error with Swift generics and associated types

Tags: generics, swift, associated-types

The following Swift code repeatedly crashes the compiler. What am I missing?

```
protocol Props {
    typealias ComponentType: Component<Self>
}

class Component<PropsType: Props> {
}

class FooProps : Props {
    typealias ComponentType = FooComponent<FooProps>
}

class FooComponent<PropsType: Props> : Component<PropsType> {

}
```

Comment: a crash in the compiler is always a bug, regardless of how right or wrong the code might be

Comment: Yeah, but that doesn't mean my code is correct (i suspect it isn't) -- if the code is wrong, maybe the right code won't crash the compiler. And if the code is right, then I'm in need of a workaround for that compiler bug

Comment: I don't know what your goal is but what is causing the crash is the line " typealias ComponentType = FooComponent<FooProps>"
I don't think its necessary because if you declare a simple type alias like  "typealias T = Int" in Props, you can use it as nested type of FooProps. 

Anyway, i think you can't use the "typealias ComponentType = Component<Self>" 
Try run this statment "var ComponentType:FooProps.ComponentType = FooComponent()" and you will see the program run into a infinitive loop.

Answer (score 2):

There have been some good discussions on the use of generics in protocols.

http://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/03/playing-with-swift/

http://schani.wordpress.com/2014/06/11/associated-types-considered-weird

That second article is quite illuminating for your issue.  Simply put, swift doesn't have generic types for protocols.  Hope this was useful.